# Problema con interfaz gráfica y socket en java

Tags: java, socket, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo un programa en java que conecte un cliente y un servidor por medio de un socket TCP utilizado la interfaz gráfica de usuario de java. El programa compila bien pero el problema está cuando ejecuto el servidor, ya que no muestra siquiera la ventana y no sé porqué se produce este error de ejecución.

---

Anexo el código de mi proyecto

MiSocket.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MiServer extends JFrame
{
    private JTextArea area;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket cliente;
    private int port=8080;

    public MiServer()
    {
        setSize(400,400);
        setTitle("Server");
        area = new JTextArea();
        cliente = null;
        scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout());
        getContentPane().add(scroll);

        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            cliente = server.accept();
            area.append(("Ya se conecto un cliente desde: " +
                cliente.getInetAddress().getHostName()+ 
        "("+cliente.getPort()+")"));


                new Conexion(cliente,area).start();

            server.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e1) 
        {
            System.err.println();
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }               
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiServer fr = new MiServer();
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    
}
```

Conexion.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Conexion extends Thread {
    private JTextArea area;
    private Socket cliente=null;
    private BufferedReader entrada;
    private DataOutputStream salida;
    private String llego,nombreDirIP;
    public Conexion(Socket cliente, JTextArea area){    
        this.area=area;
        this.cliente=cliente;
        nombreDirIP=cliente.getInetAddress().toString();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
            entrada=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliente.getInputStream()));
            salida = new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            do{
                llego=entrada.readLine();
                area.append(llego);
                salida.writeInt(llego.length());
            }while(llego.length()!=0);

            entrada.close();
            cliente.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        area.append("Se desconecto"+nombreDirIP);
    }
}
```

MiCliente.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MiCliente extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea area;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JButton boton;
    private JTextField campo;
    private Socket cliente;
    private PrintWriter alservidor;
    private DataInputStream delservidor;
    private String host,teclado;
    public MiCliente(){
        setSize(300,300);
        area= new JTextArea();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        boton = new JButton("Enviar");
        campo = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        scroll.setBounds(0,0,280,230);
        getContentPane().add(boton);
        boton.setBounds(200,230,100,25);
        getContentPane().add(campo);
        campo.setBounds(0,230,200,25);
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{
                    host = "localhost";
                    cliente = new Socket(host,8080);
                    alservidor = new PrintWriter(cliente.getOutputStream());
                    delservidor = new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

                }catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MiCliente fr = new MiCliente();
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la razón por la que no se muestra el frame del servidor es porque se queda esperando la conexión en la linea de `cliente = server.accept();`, de ese punto no pasa hasta que algún cliente se conecte y claro tienes el `setVisible(true);` en el main donde se ejecuta **después de** hacer la espera por conexión, lo mas preciso seria, por ejemplo, hacer visible el frame desde el constructor **antes de** aceptar las conexiones entrantes.

Tambien, a manera de una humilde sugerencia, gestiona las conexiones de `Socket` y `ServerSocket` con un `Thread` dedicado solo a ello y que se ejecute indefinidamente, con eso garantizas atender multiples peticiones de conexión.

Comment: Es cierto, ya lo modifiqué colocando la inicialización del socket después de llamar a `setVisible()` y ya lo ejecuta bien. Muchas gracias por tu atuda Johnny :D

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ahora sé mejor cómo hacer una conexión a socket más estiizada ahora :D. Mil gracias.
Un abrazo.